# Gson parsing fails for signalr in onMessageReceived method in Release apk Android Java

Tags: android, gson, signalr, proguard, signalr-hub

I was successful in implementing SignalR in Android Java code.

Everything is working fine. I was able to make connection, send and receive messages.

But, when I am testing the functionality in the signed release apk, I get the following log in onMessageReceived:

```
2022-03-27 11:52:42.725 8615-14192/? E/onMessageReceived: {"I":null}
```

which normally is like
{"I": "0"}

***this happens with all the other jsons I recieve.***

To the extent I understand, this is happening because of GSON which is not able to parse the json correctly in the signed release apk.

I made

```
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false
```

and things started to act normal in signed release apk.

```
mHubConnection.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(final JsonElement json) {
                Log.e("onMessageReceived ", json.toString());

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                        
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I went through various webpages and added the below lines to the proguard-rules.pro, but nothing changes in this regard:

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}

# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# Gson specific classes
#-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.code.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.JsonParser.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.mychatapp.models.** { *; }
-keep class com.mychatapp.util.** { *; }
-keep class com.mychatapp.chat.** { *; }


-keep class com.microsoft.signalr.** { *; }
-keep interface com.microsoft.signalr.** { *; }


# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
```

**EDIT**

I have kept the connection part and receiver part in a Service and I am calling the service like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_USER_NAME, userName);
intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_GROUP_CODE, groupCode);
intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_GROUP_NAME, groupName);
intent.setClass(this, SignalRService.class);
bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Here is my service code where I am creating the connection and receiving the message:

```
public class SignalRService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = "SignalRService";

    private HubConnection mHubConnection;
    private HubProxy mHubProxy;
    private Handler mHandler; 
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder(); 

    private final String SERVER_URL = "";
    private final String SERVER_HUB_CHAT_NAME = "MyHub";
    private final String SET_USER_NAME = "SetUserName";
    private final String JOIN_GROUP = "JoinGroup";

    private String userName;

    private String groupName;

    private String groupCode;

    private String accessToken;

    private ArrayList<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();

    public HubProxy getHubProxy() {
        return mHubProxy;
    }

    public SignalRService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int result = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mHubConnection.stop();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Return the communication channel to the service.
        connect();

        onMessageReceived();

        return mBinder;
    }

   
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SignalRService getService() {
            // Return this instance of SignalRService so clients can call public methods
            return SignalRService.this;
        }
    }

    public void connect() {
        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());

        mHubConnection = new HubConnection(SERVER_URL);

        mHubProxy = mHubConnection.createHubProxy(SERVER_HUB_CHAT_NAME);

        ClientTransport clientTransport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(mHubConnection.getLogger());

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SignalRFuture<Void> signalRFuture = mHubConnection.start(clientTransport);

                try {
                    Log.i("CONNECTION", "before connection");

                    signalRFuture.get();

                    Log.i("CONNECTION", "after connection");

                    mHubProxy.invoke(SET_USER_NAME, new Object[]{userName});

                    Log.e("Connection", mHubConnection.getConnectionData());

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(mHubConnection.getConnectionData());

                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    String name = jsonObject.getString("name");

                    if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(SERVER_HUB_CHAT_NAME)) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Connected!");

                        sendBroadcast(Constants.ACTION_CONNECTION, "Connected");
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Failed");

                        sendBroadcast(Constants.ACTION_CONNECTION, "Connection Failed");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());

                    Toast.makeText(SignalRService.this, "Connection Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    sendBroadcast(Constants.ACTION_CONNECTION, "Connection Failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void onMessageReceived() {
        mHubConnection.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(final JsonElement json) {
                Log.e("onMessageReceived ", json.toString() + " " + groupName);

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json.toString());

                            if(jsonObject.has("A")) {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("A");

                                final Message message = new Message();

                                final String user = jsonArray.get(0).toString();
                                final String receivedMsg = jsonArray.get(1).toString();

                                message.setMessage(receivedMsg);

                                // set message type (self or other)
                                message.setSelf(user.equalsIgnoreCase(userName));

                                message.setUserName(user);

                                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                                String hour = String.format(Locale.US, "%02d", cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                                String minute = String.format(Locale.US, "%02d", cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

                                final String time = hour + ":" + minute;

                                message.setDateAndTime(time);

                                messageList.add(message);

                                sendBroadcast(Constants.ACTION_MESSAGE, "");
                            } else if(jsonObject.has("I")) {
                                final String value = jsonObject.getString("I");

                                if(value.equals("0")) {
                                    mHubProxy.invoke(JOIN_GROUP, groupName, accessToken, groupCode);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendBroadcast(final String action, final String connectionMsg) {
        Intent local = new Intent();

        local.setAction(action);

        if(action.equals(Constants.ACTION_CONNECTION)) {
            local.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_CONNECTION_STATUS, connectionMsg);
        } else if(action.equals(Constants.ACTION_MESSAGE)) {
            local.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_MESSAGE_LIST, messageList);
        }

        sendBroadcast(local);
    }
}
```

When onMessageReceived is called by the SignalR code libraries, the method argument JsonElement is converted to string and displayed in the log.

When running the app directly on device and emulator the log is displayed as:

```
2022-03-27 11:52:42.725 8615-14192/? E/onMessageReceived: {"I":"0"}
```

And, when this is done on a device using a signed releaase apk, I get:

```
2022-03-27 11:52:42.725 8615-14192/? E/onMessageReceived: {"I":null}
```

I need to point out that this is coming from backend and whatever JsonElement is provided by SignalR is displayed in the log. If I set

```
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false
```

This returns the correct json in the release apk as well.

Comment: "which normally is like {"I": "0"}". Do you mean the field is named "I"? Please provide the code of the classes you are trying to serialize. Your ProGuard configuration only seems to specify for some classes to keep all their members. Alternatively you can also annotate the fields with Gson's [`@SerializedName`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html).

Comment: I agree with you for @SerializedName as that will solve the parsing issue. But, I am getting this {"I":"0"} In onMessageReceived() in the JSONElement from SignalR library. I have shared the log in the question.

Comment: With debug apk I get the json string as {"I":"0"} but for release apk I get the json string {"I":null}. Not sure, what I am doing wrong here. @Marcono1234 thank you for replying.

Comment: Is your `"0"` of type `String` in your source code, or is it a class for which you have written a custom Gson type adapter? Please try creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide the code here (or link to it).

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I am familiar enough with SignalR or Android to help you with this. If possible, try to further reduce your code to only what is needed to reproduce this issue. Currently without full code it might be difficult for others to reproduce. As side note, instead of converting `JsonElement -> JSON string -> JSONObject` you can cast the Gson `JsonElement` to Gson's [`JsonObject`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) (or use `getAsJsonObject()`) and then directly work on that.